# What is the filename for my contacts?

Tags: contacts

What is the filename for my contacts on my optimus M running froyo?

Comment: This question might be easier to find if you ask the question in the title :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's contacts.db but it's not a normal file or directory, it's a SQLite3 database in the following location which you'll need root to access:

```
data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db
```

Comment: oh, if you meant the app, it's what Matthew Read said

Comment: Could go either way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Contacts are stored in a database.  If you mean the filename of the app, it's probably Contacts.apk in /system/apps/.